# How do I delete a forked GitHub repo that's unavailable due to DCMA takedown?

Tags: github, repository

Does anyone know how to delete a forked GitHub repo that's been subject to a DCMA takedown? 
The repo is there (with a DCMA banner) but I can't do anything to it. I've tried clicking the 'settings' tab but nothing happens.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can not delete that repository on your own. I also had a fork that's been subject to DCMA  takedown. I send a mail at [GitHub Contact](https://github.com/contact) and requested to delete that repository. After 2 days, the repository was deleted.

You can also check the GitHub article on [DCMA Takedown Policy](https://help.github.com/articles/dmca-takedown-policy/).

Comment: Why don't they just show the delete button? It seems to be design bug.